# Validate and add http and/or www to string using javascript

Tags: javascript, string, http, concatenation

in javascript I get a string that should be something like:

- website.tld/something
- www.website.tld/something
- http://www.website.tld/something

(also third level and lower domains)

I need that 1st the string is validate, 2nd if the string isn't in the third case (http://www.website.tld/something), it has to concat "http://" and/or "www".

Anyone has some tip or knows where to find a ready-to-use script that implement this?

Comment: just to clarify you want to see if they are all valid then if the string deesn't have www or http then concat www and www ?

Comment: Yes I want first to validate, than add http and www if they're missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jQuery (or can use it), I recommend the excellent validator plugin which has a built-in function which validates [jQuery Validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

It's easy to use, and works well

DISCLAIMER: I am not involved in this project nor knowing the creator. Just a simple satisfied user ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression to match to see what action you should take.